# Solution for $dX=dt+2\sqrt{X}dW$ with positive-valued $\sqrt{X}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a Brownian motion $B$, $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and the stochastic process $X:=(\sqrt{x}+B)^2$.

I want to show, that $X$ is a solution of the SDE

$$dX = dt +2\sqrt{X} dW$$

where $W$ is some brownian motion.

Applying ito's rule for $f(x)=x^2$ I find

$$
\begin{align}
dX=df(\sqrt{x}+B)&=f'(\sqrt{x}+B) d(\sqrt{x}+B)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\sqrt{x}+B)d[\sqrt{x}+B]\\
&=2(\sqrt{x}+B)dB+\frac{1}{2}2d[B]\\
&=2(\sqrt{x}+B)dB+dt\\
\end{align}$$

Now, I'm skeptical, if this already shows, that $X$ is a solution of the SDE, because of following reason:

Shouldn't $\sqrt{X}$ be positive process, since

$$\sqrt{X}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x}+B)^2}=|\sqrt{x}+B|\quad ?$$

Is there a way to find a brownian motion $W$, such that

$$(\sqrt{x}+B)dB = |\sqrt{x}+B|dW\quad ?$$

Or am I "overinterpreting" the notion of $\sqrt{X}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to find a Brownian motion $W$ such that $(\sqrt{x}+B)dB = |\sqrt{x}+B|dW$.  Specifically, let $W_t := \int_0^t \operatorname{sgn}(\sqrt{x}+B_s)dB_s$.  Then $W$ is a Brownian motion by Levy's characterization of Brownian motion, and by associativity of stochastic integrals $$|\sqrt{x}+B|dW = |\sqrt{x}+B|\operatorname{sgn}(\sqrt{x}+B)dB = (\sqrt{x}+B)dB.$$

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for the fast reply!